# TCP client socket connecting with public server IP in dart

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, socket.io

I have a server running on my local machine, i have opened a port on my router and want to use that from the clients to connect to my server using my public IP address.

[Server Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7r92.png)

Getting an error on the client side while trying to establish a connection.

```
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = 39.41.**,***, port = 50640
```

[Client Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwhDE.png)

Comment: post the code instead of screenshot.

Comment: that error there, it means, there is no server on the address you are trying to connect

Comment: Sounds like port forwarding issues. Have you checked your router configuration and e.g. tested with some other program to see if the port is actually open and forwards traffic to your computer?

Comment: @julemand101 I have added a virtual server with port number and my local ip address of the server. When i check for port by pinging it using a website. It says the port is closed. It was working a few days back. Could it the ISP blocking the ports?

Comment: Well, maybe talk with your ISP about the issue? Are you sure you have a public IPv4 address? A lot of ISP's are now using NAT shared IP's so they can use less IPv4 addresses. You can try see in your router what IPv4 address it has been given by the ISP and see if it is the same IP you get when using a service like whatismyipaddress.com .

Comment: @julemand101Just checked under the WAN setting of my router and the website, The IP address is same. It was working a few days back and suddenly stopped working which is the surprising part in this. Thanks for the response.